# How can I center my two blue boxes here?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to center my two blue boxex shown in the example below using CSS Flexbox. I tried to center them with both align-items: center; and justify-content: center; but it is not working.

Thanks for the help.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#first {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

#loadingBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: purple;
}

#inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
    <div id="inner"></div>
    <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="loadingBar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Declare the `flex-box` rules to the containing element of the two boxes you need to align center, `flex-box` has a direct parent-to-child sort of relationship. To achieve the intended behaviour, using `flex-box`, `display: flex`, and any flex alignment properties, should be declared on the parent element.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError I have tried wit that method. I added ```display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;``` to the parent div with id #first for the two inner divs with id #inner, but they are not working. I have updated my code. Please see.

Comment: Your `display: flex` rule on `#first` is being over-qualified by another `display` rule (`display: inline-block`) further down the cascade order for that (`#first`) selector. Remove it, `display: inline-block` on `#first`, to observe the intended behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added to the "First" Class `display:flex align-items: center;`Then margin for the boxes

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  #container {
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
   background-color: green;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
  }
  #first {
   width: 50%;
      display: flex;
     background-color: red;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
   background-color: red;
  }
  #loadingBar {
   width: 100%;
   height: 20px;
   background-color: purple;
  }
  #inner {
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="first">
   <div id="inner"></div>
       <div id="inner"></div>
       <div id="inner"></div>
   <div id="inner"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="loadingBar"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I do not want to add any extra div though. Is it possible?

Comment: @Zip Yes sure, I've Edited my answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` on the element containing the blue boxes. Justify content centers the elements inside it, if you use it in the blue box it will center content inside the blue box, if any.